# rigidbody.MovePosition wont work

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript

The error is

```
Unity.Engine.Component does not contain a definition for MovePosition 
and no extension method MovePosition accepting a first argument of type  
Unity.engine.Component could be found.
```

This function is meant to delay the traveling time my projectile travels after shot from the gun.

```
 public class Projetil2 : MonoBehaviour {

// Use this for initialization
void FixedUpdate()
{
    rigidbody.MovePosition(transform.position + transform.rotation     
      *Time.deltaTime);
}
}
```

Comment: Does using `GetComponent<Rigidbody>().MovePosition(...)` work? The inherited `rigidbody` MonoBehaviour var was removed in Unity 5.

Answer (score 0):

```
transform.position + transform.rotation ?
```

transform.position  is Vector3 and transform.rotation is a Quaternion. You can't add Vector 3 and Quaternion together.

You can just do this

```
rigidbody.MovePosition(transform.position + transform.forward * Time.deltaTime);
```

Also, you can no longer access rigidbody directly in Unity 5. You need to use getComponent for that like this

```
Rigidbody rbd = GetComponent<Rigidbody> ();
rbd.MovePosition(transform.position + transform.forward * Time.deltaTime);
```

Comment: I get another error that way it says getComponent needs the reference to an object. And you're right it was .foward, not .rotation

Comment: Do you get this error when you play the game or during compile time? Compile time = when the game wont compile....

Answer (score 0):

Basically to use the methods of any component you should have a reference of that object. So First of all declare a RigidBody/RigidBody2D object accordingly.

```
 RigidBody rBody;
    void Awake()
    {
     rBody = GetComponent<RigidBody>();
    }
```

// **Note**:  If you want the object to move in a reliable predictable way but still allow physics interactions, use MovePosition (set the object to kinematic if you want it to be unaffected by physics but still be able to affect other things, and uncheck kinematic if you want both objects to be able to be acted on by physics. If you want to move your object but let physics handle the finer details, add a force.

```
void FixedUpdate()
{
    rBody.MovePosition(transform.position + transform.rotation     
      *Time.deltaTime);
}
```